# Is it possible with Python `coverage` library get coverage report with Total summary if I test only one file?

Tags: python, code-coverage, pytest

I am using coverage library or pytest-cov plugin to produce coverage report. My program consist of from only one file.

And for one file coverage library does not produce Total summary line. 
Also when I tried to list all files like that using `pytest-cov`

```
... --cov=a.py --cov=b.py ...
```

It also does not produce total summary.

Is it possible to always get line with total summary?

Comment: You mention a.py and b.py, but your title tells you have only one file. This is confusing. If I have only one file I also have no TOTAL line. You will have to add a second python file (empty) as a workaround

Answer (score 0):

You can use -a for append for total summary

```
coverage run a.py
coverage run -a b.py
coverage run -a c.py
```

Print the report

```
coverage report -m
```

Output:Report (for example)

```
Name             Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
----------------------------------------------
a.py           97      1    99%   95
b.py            1      0   100%
c.py            10      0   100%
----------------------------------------------
TOTAL               108      1    99%
```

Comment: What if I have only one file so I can not use -a option?

Comment: @Raf -a you can use or need to use when you want to append result from multiple python file. So, if you have only one python file then there is no need of it

Comment: However, even with one file I want to get line with total summary.

Comment: Looks like i didnt get thr question. Can you please explain a bit more.

Comment: I have a program, it consist of from only one file. When I test it, coverage reports does not produce summary/total line. I was wondered is it possible to get that summary?

Comment: Looks like some issue with your version. You can run #coverage run filename and then #coverage report -m, it should produce report in same format as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: If you have only one file (only a.py, not b.py not c.py) the TOTAL disappears. This is intelligent, as the average coverage of one file is identical to the total of one file − but is bad when you want to regex to get the total coverage into a variable for further processing. For that the word coverage is needed!